# Why does $\lim_{ t\to 0} \frac{o(t^2)}{t} = 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

> Why does $\lim_{ t\to 0} \frac{o(t^2)}{t} = 0$?

$\sqrt t = o(t^2) \implies \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sqrt t}{t} = \infty$

Maybe I don't understand completely the little-o notation.

Comment: There is a difference between little-o notations.  In algorithms, we consider little-$o$ as $t$ goes to infinity.  In that case, $\sqrt{t}\in o(t^2)$ as it has a smaller growth rate.  

In your situation, you want something that approaches $0$ slower (or that $1/t$ approaches infinity faster).

Comment: So, whenever you use a $o$ (or $O$, etc.) you need to include something like "as $t \to 0$" in there.  Perhaps it's understood, but (as we see here) if not it leads to error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a right neighbourhood of zero, it is not true that $\sqrt{t}=o(t^2)$.

We say that $f(t)=o(t^2)$ in a right neighbourhood of zero when:
$$ \lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{f(t)}{t^2} = 0.\tag{1}$$
In particular, the previous identity implies that $\frac{f(t)}{t^2}$ is bounded in in a right neighbourhood of zero, say $\left|\frac{f(t)}{t^2}\right|\leq C,$ hence:
$$ \left|\frac{f(t)}{t}\right| = |t|\cdot\left|\frac{f(t)}{t^2}\right|\leq C\,|t|\tag{2} $$
implies:
$$ \lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{f(t)}{t} = 0 \tag{3}$$
as wanted.

Comment: @AlonAlon: you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(t) = o(t^2)$ as $t\to 0$, then $\lim_{t \to 0} f(t)/t^2 = 0$. Thus

$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(t)}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(t)}{t^2}\cdot t = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(t)}{t^2}\cdot \lim_{t\to 0} t = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You may see $f(t)=o(t^2)$ as any function of the form $$f(t)=t^2
   \times \epsilon(t)$$ where $\epsilon(t) \to 0$ as $t\to 0$.

**2.** You may see $f(t)=O(t^2)$ as any function of the form $$f(t)=t^2
   \times \epsilon(t)$$ where there exists $C$ such that  $|\epsilon(t) |\leq C$ as $t\to 0$.